# How can I stop nginx failling over when openresty throws runtime error deploying cert

Tags: nginx, lua, amazon-ami, openresty

We are using openresty and the lua-resty-auto-ssl package to generate certificates from Lets Encrypt but lately the server keeps falling over. Im guessing its triggered when a certificate trys to auto renew as generating a certificate for first time works fine ... the error we are seeing is

```
2019/05/12 08:25:24 [error] 2623#2623: *1024227 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: ...sty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/resty/auto-ssl/servers/hook.lua:40: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
        ...sty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/resty/auto-ssl/servers/hook.lua:40: in function 'server'
        .../local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/resty/auto-ssl.lua:99: in function 'hook_server'
        content_by_lua(nginx.conf:194):2: in function <content_by_lua(nginx.conf:194):1>, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /deploy-cert HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8999"
```

From what I can see in the error it is failing to assert something when trying to deploy the cert which could be any of 4 things

```
assert(params["domain"])
assert(params["fullchain"])
assert(params["privkey"])
assert(params["expiry"])
```

Im a bit stuck to what I can do, its no good having the server dropping out on use. Thats the last error thats reported before the server goes offline so im guessing thats the cause? but not 100% sure.

Is there anywhere I can look to find out more information what causes the crash. Im new to nginx/openresty so fumbling my round a bit. Has anyone come across a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it all in a function and call it with [`pcall`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pcall) or [`xpcall`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-xpcall) and add some logic to deal with the error.